# Boot problems after update

Tags: boot

After an update, I was asked to restart, and after the restart, I couldn't boot. I was stuck on this screen:

[image]

Afterwards, I tried solving this problem on my own, and I ended up nowhere.
However, I think I found potential problems.

[image]

```
gpu-manager.service

lightdm.service

plymouth-quit-wait.service

plymouth-quit.service

pppd-dns.service
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! A simple fix really. Purged light dm, and installed it again.